# CreateFile doesn't prevents other processes from opening my device

Tags: createfile, wdf

I'm using CreateFile to open a connection to my USB hardware. If I have two (or more) hardwares connected to the PC I would like to prevent several instances (different PIDs) of my PC-application to connect to the very same hardware.

I thought this was accomplished by running CreateFile with dwShareMode = 0. For some reason this doesn't work. Several different instances of the PC-application will get a valid handle when running CreateFile towards the same USB-device.

```
hDev = CreateFile(
    "\\\\?\\usb#vid_0442&pid_0891&mi_01#6&2ea0fbc8&0&0001#{ff646f80-8def-11d2-9449-00105a075f6b}"
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL
);
```

If possible I would like to make this work as I want without changing the driver since that will invoke driver certificate signing, yadayada...

What have I missed?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

WdfDeviceInitSetExclusive(...) at EvtDeviceAdd made it work *re-signing my driver* 8-]